# Palindrome logic in python: What is wrong with this program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def isPalindrome(word):

    l = len(word)

    for i in range(l/2):
        if(word[i] != word[i+l-1]):
            return 0

    return 1

def main():

    print("\n\n\tTo Check if the word is a Palindrome\n\n")

    word = raw_input("Enter a word : ")

    if(isPalindrome(word) == 1):
        print("It is a Palindrome")

    elif:
        print("It is not a Palindrome")

main()
```

In my opinion everything is right in the program. It goes good when I enter a word which is not a palindrome but when I enter a palindrome it gives an error like this:

```
Enter a word : madam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "temp.py", line 6, in isPalindrome
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: What is wrong is not an appropriate question, what error are you receiving, what is your expected output - what are you getting? E.g. In `python3` `range(l/2)` will be an error because `/` will return a `float` (use `//`) - is that the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that is wrong is: `elif:` - if you're using else-if you should provide a condition, the fix in this case it to change it to `else:`

Second, the `if` should be: `if(word[i] != word[l-i-1]):` in order for the function to work (check that each letter is equal to its equivalent in the word).

Third, less critical but still important: keep the styling:

1. remove redundant braces
2. use proper naming convention (snake-case - not camel-case)
3. use True/False as return values instead of 1/0
4. use floor division `//` (as AChampion mentioned in the comments)

Complete code (fixed):

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    l = len(word)
    for i in range(l//2):
        if word[i] != word[l-i-1]:
            return False
    return True


def main():
    print("\n\n\tTo Check if the word is a Palindrome\n\n")
    word = raw_input("Enter a word : ")
    if is_palindrome(word):
        print("It is a Palindrome")
    else:
        print("It is not a Palindrome")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: While it looks like the OP is using Py2 - it's probably safer to use `range(l//2)` which works for py2 & 3.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic for checking palindrome should be:

```
if(word[i] != word[l-1-i]):
     return 0
```

It's okay to do `l/2` if you're on python 2 but python 3 will produce the result as a floating point value.
Your code seems to be in py3.

And you *need* to give a condition to the `elif` block. Otherwise, change it to `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `word[i+l-1]` to `word[l-i-1]`:

```
def isPalindrome(word):

    l = len(word)

    for i in range(l // 2):
        if(word[i] != word[l-i-1]):
            return 0

    return 1
```

The goal is to get the `word[l-i-1` to count down while `i` is counting up; hence, you need to subtract *i* rather than add it.

Also, I would change the `l/2` to `l // 2` so that it works in Python 3 as well.

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should round the l/2 value

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    l = len(word)
    for i in range(round(l/2)):
        if(word[i] != word[i+l-1]):
            return 0
        return 1

print("\n\n\tTo Check if the word is a Palindrome\n\n")

word = input("Enter a word : ")
if(isPalindrome(word) == 1):
    print("It is a Palindrome")
else:
    print("It is not a Palindrome")
```